# HTTPS form url in Smarty template

Tags: https, smarty

I need to change form action urls from http to https, I've added the following code to .htaccess but that doesn't change form urls:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The ecommerce system uses the Smarty function _createUrl for the form action url, and I see in that function in Abstract.php there is the following code:

```
$isSecure = preg_match('/on/i', $_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 1 : 0;
```

So I guess either that is not working or it's being overridden.

If I add the following line below the above check, it makes no difference.

```
$isSecure = 1;
```

However if I add the following then the form action url becomes a relative path and therefore uses https.

```
$aParamList['secure'] = 1;
```

Any ideas please?